# Applying a style globally (example in fancyhdr - across page styles)

Tags: macros, fancyhdr

Imagine I wanted to make **all** footers, pagestyles, etc. in bold. There's nothing like a `\globalpagestyle` or something, so my take on the problem was something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}%
\let\Rfoot\rfoot%
\renewcommand\rfoot[1]{\textbf{\Rfoot{#1}}}%
\rfoot{I want to be bold! All the time}%
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{plain}
Footer up your ass
\newpage
\pagestyle{plain}
Cookie
\end{document}
```

...but I suspect I've been somewhat clumsy here. How to apply a style (be it bold series, be it a box, be it some weird tikzpicture background, etc.) to every future footer?

I'm looking for a solution that involves the use of the `\textbf` command so that this solution can be applied to different styles as well (imagine you want a box around everything, etc.)

Comment: Use `\renewcommand\rfoot[1]{\Rfoot{\bfseries#1}}`.

Comment: @PeterGrill Hm... I'm sorry I changed my question slightly because I see you nailed this one in exactly a fashion that doesn't help me any further. Sorry for being unclear initially :-)

Comment: No problem. I changed the answer slightly as well :-). Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: @PeterGrill Thanks. It was actually a conflicting package (that's also not from CTAN - worst mistake of my life) that was causing this behaviour. Your solution worked for me. I can't believe I didn't see that I had to swap around the commands to `Rfoot` first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `\renewcommand\rfoot[1]{\Rfoot{\bfseries#1}}` seems to work:

[image]

Or you could use `\renewcommand\rfoot[1]{\Rfoot{\textbf{#1}}}` as well.

If, instead you want to put a box around each footer text use `\renewcommand\rfoot[1]{\Rfoot{\fbox{#1}}}`:

[image]

### Code: `Bold`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\let\Rfoot\rfoot
\let\Lfoot\lfoot
\let\Cfoot\cfoot
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand\rfoot[1]{\Rfoot{\bfseries#1}}
\renewcommand\cfoot[1]{\Cfoot{\bfseries#1}}
\renewcommand\lfoot[1]{\Lfoot{\bfseries#1}}
\rfoot{right footer}
\cfoot{center footer}
\lfoot{left footer}

\begin{document}
Some text
\end{document}
```

### Code: `\fbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\let\Rfoot\rfoot
\let\Lfoot\lfoot
\let\Cfoot\cfoot
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand\rfoot[1]{\Rfoot{\fbox{#1}}}
\renewcommand\cfoot[1]{\Cfoot{\fbox{#1}}}
\renewcommand\lfoot[1]{\Lfoot{\fbox{#1}}}
\rfoot{right footer}
\cfoot{center footer}
\lfoot{left footer}

\begin{document}
Some text
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you've loaded `fancyhdr` package and used `\pagestyle{plain}`, why not to redefine plain style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}%

\fancypagestyle{plain}
{
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[R]
{
    \textbf{I want to be bold! All the time}
}
}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{plain}
Footer up your ass
\newpage
\pagestyle{plain}
Cookie
\newpage
\pagestyle{fancy}
this is with fancy style
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]